# python, exercise, for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
def drawTriangle(height):

    for i in range(1, height+1):

        for j in range(1, height+1-i ):  # for space
            print(" ", end = "")

        for j in range(1, i+1): # for increasing numbers
            print(j, end = "")

        for j in range(i-1, 0, -1 ):   # for decreasing numbers
            print(j, end = "")
           # if i == height:
            #    print(j, end = "")
        print() # for new lines

        for j in range(1, i+1):
            if i == height:
                print(j, end = "")
                sum = j+j
                print(sum)
            else:
                print("", end = "")
        for j in range(i-1, 0 , -1):
            if i == height:
                print(j, end = "")
            else:
                print("", end = "")

drawTriangle(7)
```

how can i find the last row's summation of this triangle?
Your function must return the sum of all integers on the last line of the triangle. For example

> 16 for height=4, 4 for height =2, and 49 for height=7. Your function must use another function called get_row to figure out the row to be printed. This function must get the row height and return the necessary line. For example, it shall return “1” for row_height=1, “1 2 1” for row_height=2, “1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1” for row_height=5.

Comment: Is this your attempt at solving this homework problem?  Does it work?  If not, what doesn't work?

Comment: This is clearly homework, do you want us to do it for you?

Comment: Should we tell him that the sum of row N is N*N?

Comment: This is vastly more complex than it needs to be, you're not meeting the brief, you need another function and your functions to return a value, you also don't need so many iterations and you should use unique values for variables.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, your approach is too complex, and a bit overkill.
You're also missing a critical step in the problem statement, "Your function must use another function called get_row to figure out the row to be printed."

Instead of calculating the `sum` inside the loops, first create the entire row, and only once you have reached the last line of the triangle, i.e. "height", calculate that row's sum.

Here's a simplified approach with comments to explain some of the logic:

```
def drawTriangle(height):
    for step in range(1,height+1):
        row = get_row(step)
        if step == height:
            print(sum(row))

def get_row(step):
    row = []
    # start building the row of integers 
    # from 1 up to this step height
    # e.g. [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    for i in range(1,step+1):
        row.append(i)
    # then append integers from this height, 
    # e.g. 7 (to avoid duplicate from previous loop) down to 1
    for i in reversed(range(1, step)):
        row.append(i)
    return row

drawTriangle(7)
```

The last line on the triangle of input `7` yields `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`, the sum of which is returned as output:

```
49
```

Note: as mentioned in a comment, confirm this makes sense by "sum of row N is N*N": `7 x 7 = 49`